# How to enable Cryptographic CoProcessor in IBM zD&T EE?

Tags: zos

I am currently using zD&T EE V12.0.5.
In order to implement MQ queue manager channel connection with SSL method, we are preparing encryption key management using ICSF function of z/OS 2.1.
[system]
processors 3 cp cp ziip
[adjunct-processors]
crypto 0
As mentioned above,I defined a CoProcessor in the [adjunct-processors] stanza of the zD&T devmap, but the CoProcessor is not enabled when I start ICSF. 
(The following message is output to the message at CSF startup)

CSFM505I CRYPTOGRAPHY - THERE ARE NO ACTIVE CRYPTGRAPHIC COPROCESSORS.

CSFM133I THERE ARE NO ACTIVE PKCF11 COPROCESSORS.

What are the possible causes?
Also, what kind of investigation can I do to find out the cause?

Comment: Where is this zD&T EE running? I guess that there’s no ICSF in distributed HW and that’s why it days there are no active PKCF11 coprocessors.

Answer (score 0):

Likely issue is that the ICSF DOMAIN is not getting picked up by default.

DOMAIN is optional (per documentation) and has a default value that is obtained from the activation profile for the LPAR. Since this is a ZD&T environment there is no "activation profile" and thus the default is not likely getting set and so must be manually set. There can be multiple DOMAIN's assigned for a system (you can have multiple `crypto` statements for ZD&T or you could have multiple `"usage domains"` in an activation profile) but you can only use one. Based on poster's setting of `"crypto 0"` then DOMAIN(0) should be set in CSFPRMxx member of parmlib.

Doc on ICSF options can be found here: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.5.0?topic=start-parameters-in-installation-options-data-set

Comment: any reference you can provide to describe what DOMAIN(0) does?

Comment: Thank you for providing the information.   However, DOMAIN(0) has already been specified for CSFPRMxx.  
It is a situation that one z/OS environment is running on zD&T.   
Also, the result of executing the ap_query -a 0 command on the zD&T side was as follows. AWSEMO019I Query for Adjunct Processor 0 Attached domains: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15. 
Is there a way to find out what the problem is on the z/OS side?

Comment: Are you certain the ICSF started task is pointing at a CSFPRMxx member where DOMAIN(0) is specified?  Do you see DOMAIN(0) echoed in the startup messages of the ICSF started task? 

Verify which ICSF PARM member is used via the //CSFPARM DD statement in the started task JCL.

Comment: Thank you, ZEOD.
>Do you see DOMAIN(0) echoed in the startup messages of the ICSF started task?
-> YES
***<< The message at startup is as follows. >>***
CSFO0230 CKDSN(CSF.CSFCKDS)
CSFO0230 PKDSN(CSF.CSFPKDS)
CSFO0230 COMPAT(NO)
CSFO0230 SSM(YES)
CSFO0230 CHECKAUTH(NO)
CSFO0230 DOMAIN(0)
CSFO0230 USERPARM(USERPARM)
CSFO0230 REASONCODES(ICSF)
....
CSFM015I FIPS 140 SELF CHECKS FOR PKCS11 SERVICES SUCCESSFUL.
CSFM401I CRYPTOGRAPHY - SERVICES ARE NO LONGER AVAILABLE.

Comment: ZD&T 12.0.5 is older release as is z/OS 2.1.  ZD&T 12.0.5 came with z/OS 2.4. There may be incompatibility between zPDT drivers and z/OS 2.1. 
I would suggest upgrading to newer release of ZD&T and a more recent version of z/OS if possible. 
My only other suggestion would be to review the ICSF Installation docs and ensure z/OS is configured correctly but ultimately this still might not work due to the versions of software in use. https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.1.0?topic=guide-installation-initialization-customization

Comment: Thank you, ZEOD. 
Since the existing system is z/OS 2.1, we have no choice but to choose z/OS 2.1 for the development and verification environment.

Comment: I executed the following command to check the status of the encryption processor on the zD&T side.
$ ap_query -a 0
AWSEMO019I Query for Adjunct Processor 0 Attached domains: 0 1 2 3 4 5 67 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15

$ ap_vpd -a 0
AWSMAJ013I Query VPD results:
NumAdaptorsIns = 1
OpSysName = Linux
CardPartNum,CardECLevel,SerialNumber,CCA Level,CCA Build Date are set some data value.
But, It seems that no value is set in the item ,AdapterID.
AWSEMO001i Adjunct Processor manual function complete
AWSEMO008W Domain vary on: Domain 0 for AP 0 is unavailable.
Domain 1 thru 15,same.

Comment: Is there a point that could be the cause from this command result?
Also, are there any message log files to investigate for zD&T problem determination?

Comment: ZD&T 12.0.5 came with z/OS 2.4 (not 2.1) and hardware/firmware version 55.04 (GA9 I think). The firmware code provided with ZD&T 12.0.5 simply may not work with z/OS 2.1 as the crypto express level in the firmware code may be too far ahead and thus unsupported yet by older z/OS. You should be able to download later releases of ADCD from PPA assuming you are valid customer.